# Count the total number of rows in this tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, html-table, rows

I have been trying to count the total number of tr's located in my nested tbody and I am unable to get the total count. I have tried to get it using the following jQuery code but its returning a big number like 44 rows, where as I am expecting it to return 7 rows.

Could you suggest me as to where I am going wrong?

```js
var count = $("#rbe_viewTab0 table tbody tr td table tbody tr").length;
alert(count);
```

```html
<div id="rbe_viewTab0" class="nothing" style="display:block;margin-top:0px" isloaded="Y">
    <table class="wide" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table class="wide" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td id="xyz">Row 2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am expecting it to return 7 rows for the total number of rows and index as '1' for Row 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your selector may be wrong. Here is a snippet.

```js
var count = $("#rbe_viewTab0 > tbody > tr > td > table.wide > tbody > tr").length;
var index = $("#rbe_viewTab0 > tbody > tr > td > table.wide > tbody > tr > td#xyz").parent().index();
alert(count);
alert(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rbe_viewTab0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="wide">
        <tr>
          <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="xyz">Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 6</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**
Here is the selector for the index. Also updated my snippet.

```
var index = $("#rbe_viewTab0 > tbody > tr > td > table.wide > tbody > tr > td#xyz").parent().index();
```

Comment: Worked first time. Thanks.

Comment: Also if I am on the div containing Row 2, how can I get its index? Lets say that div has an id of "xyz"?

Comment: What do yo mean? Edit your question and provide an example of expected result

Comment: Edited my question and added an example of expected result. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, so if there is a content in your `<td>` the index should increase?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70789/discussion-between-the-newbie-and-ramis-wachtler).

Comment: Just wanted to get the index of that table row that has an id of xyz.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`var count = $("#rbe_viewTab0 > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr").length;
alert(count);`

Answer (score 1):

`$('tbody tbody tr').length` would do.

e.g. http://jsbin.com/bacosijina/1/edit?html,output

**Edit:** Now, that you've updated the question:
`$('table table tr').length` would do. i.e. rows in a table contained by a table

**Edit Edit:** Ok, the markup in the question changed yet again. Maybe you want to go with `$('#rbe_viewTab0 tbody tbody tr').length`

e.g. http://jsbin.com/suxolo/1/edit?html,output